# Replace column output in a more readable form Oracle - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an SQL statement :

`SELECT paymentType, OTHER_COLUMNS FROM payment;`

The output  for the column paymentType will be **ePay**, **cPay**, **dPay**, **ccPay** for electronic payment, cash payment, deposit account payment and credit card payment.

How can I make the query return the respective **description** instead of the **accronyms**, in a select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hard-code the translations

```
SELECT (CASE paymentType
             WHEN 'ePay' THEN 'electronic payment'
             WHEN 'cPay' THEN 'cash payment'
             WHEN 'dPay' THEN 'deposit account payment' 
             WHEN 'ccPay' THEN 'credit card payment'
             ELSE paymentType
         END) payment_type,
       other_columns
  FROM payment
```

Normally, though, you'd create a lookup table and join to that

```
SELECT payment_type.payment_type_description,
       <<other columns>>
  FROM payment pay
       JOIN payment_type ON (pay.paymentType = payment_type.paymentType)
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. Pb the tables are already in production and I did not cater for the description. Hence the CASE statement seems more appropriate to my needs.